# Magento 2 REST-API POST V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items either 400 or 404

Tags: rest, magento2

I'm struggling to add a product to a guest cart using the REST-API. I tried different methods that either result in 404 or 400 errors.

The first method is from the docs, or at leas how I interpret them. The second method is from another stack exchange answer. I must be overlooking or confusing something. What is the right method?

**FIRST METHOD:**

**Create a new guest cart**

Request

```
POST: V1/guest-carts
```

Response:

```
"EDzeXsnat8aODucV5zRVa6o7yChZ9je9"
```

**Add product to guest cart**

Request

```
POST: V1/guest-carts/EDzeXsnat8aODucV5zRVa6o7yChZ9je9/items

{
  "cart_item": {
    "quote_id": "EDzeXsnat8aODucV5zRVa6o7yChZ9je9",
    "product_type": "configurable",
    "sku": "032501-42",
    "qty": 1,
    "extension_attributes": {},
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "configurable_item_options": [
          {
            "option_id": "168",
            "option_value": 278
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

> 400 - Bad request

---

**SECOND METHOD:**

From [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/188469/58853) I learned that there should be an extra step in between because you have to use the actual quote id instead of the mask that is returned by `V1/guest-carts`. That changes the flow to the following.

**Create a new guest cart**

Request

```
POST: V1/guest-carts
```

Response:

```
"EDzeXsnat8aODucV5zRVa6o7yChZ9je9"
```

**Request quote id**

Request

```
GET: V1/guest-carts/EDzeXsnat8aODucV5zRVa6o7yChZ9je9
```

Response

```
{
  "id": 95563,
  // etc ...
}
```

**Add product to guest cart**

Request

```
POST: V1/guest-carts/95563/items

{
  "cart_item": {
    "quote_id": "95563",
    "product_type": "configurable",
    "sku": "032501-42",
    "qty": 1,
    "extension_attributes": {},
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "configurable_item_options": [
          {
            "option_id": "168",
            "option_value": 278
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

> 404 - No route found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use mask in the url and id itself in the payload. You can also use directly particular simple product's sku of that configurable product instead adding configurable product and options.

```
POST: V1/guest-carts/EDzeXsnat8aODucV5zRVa6o7yChZ9je9/items

{
  "cart_item": {
    "quote_id": 95563,
    "product_type": "configurable",
    "sku": "032501-42",
    "qty": 1,
    "extension_attributes": {},
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "configurable_item_options": [
          {
            "option_id": "168",
            "option_value": 278
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```